# Assigning text to specific input variables in python

Tags: python, variables, text, input, raw-input

```
print "This is a dating message that I am going to test, I want the user to be able to input their own answers."
print "I'd like for this message to work correctly, this is a dating message for Python"

print "Hi there, I think you're very cute and that's why I'm sending you this message"
print "I'm going to prompt you to see if you'd like to go on a date with me, type 'ok' to continue"

raw_input() 
print "Type 'y' if you'd like to go out, or 'n' if you're not interested."

raw_input(y) = "Hooray I'm so happy to hear that! You should text me at 888-888-8888"
raw_input(n) = "Awww darnit, well best of luck to you!"
```

I'm pretty new at programming, I'm actually in college right now, but I'm just curious I've been having trouble trying to assign specific texts like an input to input variables in python, can anybody show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) - it has lots of good info about how this sort of thing works.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` is a function that returns user's answer.

```
yesno = raw_input("Type 'y' if you'd like to go out, or 'n' if you're not interested.")

if yesno == 'y':
    print "Hooray I'm so happy to hear that! You should text me at 888-888-8888" 
else:
    print "Awww darnit, well best of luck to you!"
```

Comment: Okay I guess I need to start thinking outside of the box like this, I feel like I'm trying to over complicate things lol. TY for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I can comprehend correctly, you're looking to assign the raw_input to some variable. This would be the way to go about it

```
age =  raw_input("Enter your age: ")
print age
```

Answer (score 0):

good job on trying to learn programming. What are you trying to do?

you can use this print text out in the console:

```
print "Hello World"
```

and you can use this to prompt the user and save what is inputted:

```
something = raw_input("Just type something? ")
```

After this, you will have the user inputted string in the /something/ variable and you can print it out like this:

```
print something
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a name to a string object like this:

```
var = "This is a text string"
```

Now whenever we use `var` it refers to 'This is a text string'.

```
print var
This is a text string
```

Functions (just named chunks of code) *return* an object.  It can be any Python object, including a text string.  We can then use that function call in an assignment:

```
reply = raw_input("Please type something: ")
```

`raw_input` *returns* whatever the user typed.  Now we can use the name `reply` to refer to that string object.

Of course we can combine these:

```
prompt = "Please type something: " 
reply = raw_input(prompt)
```